# python - how do I perform the below operation in dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I had dataframe a part of which is shown below

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
                   'id1': ['676PA','676RA','197PA','197RA','199PA','199RA','834PA','834RA','950PA','950RA','952PA','952RA','953PA','953RA','954PA','954RA','956PA','956RA'],
                    'Category1' : ['P-L','FL123','P-L','FL123','P-L','FL123','P-L','FL123','FL123','P-L','P-L','FL123','FL123','P-L','FL123','P-L','P-L','FL123'],
                    'Val1' : [-4.0,39.0,-8.0,45.0,-4.0,27.0,-46.0,271.0,-70.0,3.0,-34.0,192.0,-56.0,3.0,-56.0,3.0,-52.0,292.0]
})
```

each id has two entries "PA" and "RA" with corresponding Category and Val as shown below

the sequencing of Category is incorrect and I want it to be consistent for all ids. I want P-L to come first followed by FL123 for each of the ids. I have shown the "current" and how I want to see the output below. Any help is much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Just sort the values based on those two columns. `df1.sort_values(['id1', 'Category1'])`

Comment: @Don'tAccept, that won't work since @user13412850 wants to change the order for `id1` in those cases to have the same sequence in `Category1`.

Comment: @bruno-uy, OP wants to re-order the row pairs for a given `ID` if the value in `Category1` column  for the first row for a given `ID` is `FL123`, so sorting definitely works, only the flipside is it will sort all the rows, not only the ones mentioned. But again, I don't think that should cause any problem.

Comment: thanks both but simply using df1.sort_values(['id1', 'Category1']) doesnt give me the output I wanted in my table shown in my original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit - keep historical order of IDs**

Since you want to keep the order of you IDs (so you want to maintain 676, 199 etc.) you need to create some sort of count that will count each ID with the same number (i.e 676R AND 676PA both equal 0, the next ID for both RA and PA will equal 1 and so on...).

What you can do is very similar, you just need a different temporary column:

1. Create a new temp column using `.groupby()` and `.cumcount()` where you group on the `Category1` so that it counts each category one after the other.
2. Sort on this new **new** ID column and the `Category1` column :)

```py
(
    df1
    .assign(temp = df1.groupby('Category1').cumcount())
    .sort_values(['temp','Category1'], ascending=[True, False])
)
```

*Note: This will only work if you have two categories for each ID*

**Original - If order retention isn't needed**

Like said in the comments, if it does not matter in which order the IDs appear (i.e. 197PA, 197RA can come first (but together) in your entire list) then you can use a sort. However, since you need to sort using the digits only, you need to do this in two steps (optional third):

1. Create a new column (say `temp_id`) where you replace 'PA' to be 'RA' (or vice-versa)
2. Sort by `new_id` ascending **and** `Category1` descending
3. Optional: Remove the `temp_id` column as you no longer need it.

```py
(
    df1.assign(temp_id = df1['id1'].str[:-2]) 
    .sort_values(['temp_id','Category1'], ascending=[True, False])
#     .drop('temp_id', axis=1)
)
```

Comment: thanks @Shep, that was v useful and I think I am getting answer v close to what I was expecting only issue is as you can see in my output table, my "ids" start at 676 followed by "197" followed by "199" and so on. Difference was in "950" where RA and PA sequencing was changed to match the condition for Category1. However, your output starts at "197" followed by "199". As these are historic data I would want id to be in the same sequence.

Comment: Edited with new solution to maintain order. Have you always got 2 categories for each ID? If not then another solution would be required.

Comment: thanks v much @Shep, that is what I wanted. and yes there are always 2 categories for each ids so your solution should work for my entire df! appreciate your effort again.